# Send file from container to host

Tags: docker, copy, volume, sharefile

This is what I tried:

Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT go test ./tests -v .>/outputs/report.txt
```

Command line:

```
docker run test -v /outputs:/outputs
```

I expect that the newly generated report.txt will be available in the host in the same directory. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Siyu I need to automate this. So, I cannot use docker cp as I will not have the container ID. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong with the volume notions?

Comment: sorry about the comment, I was not aware you were using volume because your option is in the wrong order, try `docker run -v /outputs:/outputs test`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you almost made it.

Try to map the volume before image name.

Instead: `docker run test -v /outputs:/outputs`

Use: `docker run -v /outputs:/outputs test`

This command will bind your local `/outputs` with the `/outputs` in the container. And remember, all commands after image name will pass a `command` to the container.

For more information see: [Docker run command docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form) and [Docker volume docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)